# How to abbreviate まつゆきそう

Tags: kanji, names, abbreviations

I was trying to abbreviate this word meaning *snowdrop*, but I can't quite get it to work. Is it even possible?

I tried with multiple ways but it changes the whole meaning. If it matters I wanted to use it as a name, but *matsuyukisō* is too long.

Comment: As a plant name, it's not too long and can't be shortened.

Comment: But if it was supposed to be a name for a person then would it be weird? Does it sound normal as a name for a girl?

Comment: まつゆき・そう can be a valid full name, where まつゆき is the family name, most probably written as 松雪.

Comment: It simply means まつゆきそう (in full) can't be used as a human name. I suppose chrysanthemum won't be a human name, which should be the same thing.

Comment: @sundowner Laws of some countries allow unique, strange or [very long](https://www.google.com/search?q=longest+human+name) names of humans... Some woman from Texas has [name with 1019 letters](https://www.thesun.co.uk/news/17252084/mother-gives-daughter-worlds-longest-name/) :) . In comparison to those, "Chrysanthemum" would be uncontroversial.

Comment: Without even checking, I'm nearly certain someone has given the name Chrysanthemum somewhere. At the same time, it would not be regarded as a "typical" name, for sure.

Comment: @Arfrever In legal terms, まつゆきそう would be surely valid. (Off topic, but a quick googling found [this (contemporary) guy](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%97%A4%E6%9C%AC%E5%A4%AA%E9%83%8E%E5%96%9C%E5%B7%A6%E8%A1%9B%E9%96%80%E5%B0%86%E6%99%82%E8%83%BD) as someone with a long name)

Comment: @Leebo How about names ending with "-wort" or "-weed"? What do you think if someone has given a name like "Bellwort" or "Ragweed" to a baby? In Japanese, I feel a person name ending with ソウ/クサ is nearly impossible, but I'm not sure if "-wort/-weed" really works as an analogy here.

Comment: @naruto I'm also not sure how well they match the feeling of ソウ/クサ, but they are definitely highly unlikely to be chosen as names, due to their unpleasant rings. It would have to be a very unusual situation for a -wort/-weed name to be given.

Comment: @naruto At least "Ambrosia" (scientific name of genus of plants whose non-scientific English name is [ragweed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ragweed)) is attested in usage as [name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambrosia_(disambiguation)#People) of humans. This genus of plants is called similarly to *Ambrosia* in most European languages (e.g. Italian/Portuguese/Spanish/Dutch *Ambrosia*, French *Ambroisie*, Danish *Ambrosie*, Swedish *Ambrosior*, Polish *Ambrozja*, Russian *Амброзия*, Slovenian/Croatian *Ambrozija*), with English, German, Finnish and Hungarian being main exceptions.

Comment: Words of Latin or Greek origin probably sound better (at least for usage in names of humans). Even if they were derived from Latin / Greek words with not very positive meanings, those original meanings might be not remembered by most humans in modern times.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your purpose matters. そう (草 in kanji, "-wort") is a suffix for a plant name, similarly to how 語 ("-ese") is a suffix for a language name and 石 ("-ite") is for a rock name. You can never use まつゆきそう as a person name, and this is not even a matter of its length!

However, if you simply drop そう, まつゆき does work as a name of a person. It's more commonly known as a family name, but it works also as a unisex given name. I found there is a [real character with this name](https://gamewith.jp/bokumono/article/show/258889) (although he happens to be a male ninja). Still, note that this plant is better known as スノードロップ than まつゆきそう (待雪草) among Japanese speakers, and many may not notice まつゆき is based on a plant name.

Likewise, [カスミソウ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%AB%E3%82%B9%E3%83%9F%E3%82%BD%E3%82%A6) only works as a plant name, but かすみ works perfectly as a girl's name.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you are considering it as a name of Japanese origin in the larger English-speaking setting / community, or simply a Japanese name said and heard by Japanese speakers.

From a Japanese perspective, まつゆきそう is not too long. Many traditional names such かんざぶろう（勘三郎） are of the same length. So people may not be inclined to shorten it as much. If you had to, you probably want to cut it at natural word boundaries - namely まつ or まつゆき. Something like まつゆ wouldn't make much sense. As a nick name, まっちゃん could work.

If you are considering it in the larger English-speaking setting / community (or in any other non-Japanese language), word boundaries won't be as relevant, and you can be more flexible. In that situation, you might find a similar-sounding name or a nick name that exist in the larger community, like "Mat", and use it as an approximation.

まつゆきそう as the name of a person sounds strange, but I think it can work as a code name for a person with the right context.